# Gazebo Environment Scale?

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-world

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
I am new in Gazebo, I work in Gazebo package in ROS (Robot Operating System).

I want to know what does it mean when write `<size>6 .2 2</size>` , mean How many meters it will be in real.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2311/gazebo-environment-scale-!/) by [Lola](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/308/lola/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

All values should be metric. So those sizes are in meters.

Take a look at [REP 103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html).

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) with karma: 319 on 2013-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0